# What is the difference between convergence of the limsup and infinity/max norm?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, normed-spaces, fourier-series

In Analysis I know that a series of functions $$ \{f_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$$ converges to $$f$$ if and only if $$\lim\sup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(f -f_n) = 0$$

Now for Fourier series, uniform convergence requires convergence in the infinity/max norm. $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n \overset{unif}\rightarrow f$$ if and only if $$ S_N(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{N}f_n$$ $$ \lim\sup_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}\|f-S_N(x)\|_{\infty} $$

But I was told that the limsup in terms of norms is not the same and also that convergence in the infinity norm is not the same as convergence of limsup for the sequence of functions $$\{f_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$$

Comment: When speaking of functions, simply saying "converges" is imprecise. You seem to be referring to pointwise convergence. Also, a limsup is of a sequence of numbers, not of functions.

Comment: As @Accumulation pointed out, simply writing $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} (f_n - f)$ doesn't mean anything. You might mean $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} (f_n(x) - f(x))$ for every $x$, or maybe $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \| f_n - f \|_{\infty}$.

Comment: @Acccumulation I mean unifrom convergence of the sequence of functions to f (i may have messed up the formulation it's been a while since I've seen it) and the other thing is, isn't there a limsup of a sequence of functions?? (I've seen it in more than one analysis book complex and real).

Comment: You could consider it to be a pointwise limsup: limsum $(f-f_n)$ is a function such $g$ such that $g(x) = \limsup(f(x)-f_n(x))$. Then when you say $(f-f_n)=0$, the zero on the RHS would be not the number zero, but the function zero, i.e. **0** is the function that takes every x to the number zero.

Answer (score 1):

Uniform convergence is stronger because the rate of convergence needs to be the same at all points $x$. The statement $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} |f(x)-f_n(x)|=0$ says $f_n$ converges to $f$ at each point $x$ but does not guarantee uniform convergence. Whereas the infinity norm $\|f-f_n\|_\infty<\epsilon$ implies that $|f(x)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$ for $n$ large enough.